# AngularJs - directive not updating controller variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Before anything I just have to say that I did a full google/stackoverflow search regarding this issue and I couldn't find anything that would help.

So, with that behind us, here's my problem:

I have this directive which should return the data selected in a simple **input type file**.
In my **console.log** the data comes out just fine but when I watch for the value change in my controller it simply never does.

Here's my directive:

```
app.directive('esFileRead', [
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            $scope: {
                esFileRead: '='
            },
            link: function ($scope, $elem) {
                $elem.bind('change', function (changeEvent) {
                    if (FileReader) {
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onload = function (loadEvent) {
                            $scope.$apply(function () {
                                $scope.esFileRead= loadEvent.target.result;
                                console.log($scope.esFileRead);
                            });
                        };
                        reader.readAsDataURL(changeEvent.target.files[0]);
                    }
                    else {
                        // FileReader not supported
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

My controller:

```
app.controller('MainController', [
    '$rootScope',
    '$scope',
    'DataManagementService',
    function ($rootScope, $scope, DataManagementService) {
        $scope.importFile = "";

        $scope.$watch('importFile', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            console.log(newValue);
            if(newValue && newValue !== oldValue) {
                DataManagementService.importData(newValue);
            }
        });

    }
]);
```

My view:

```
<input id="btnImport" type="file" es-file-read="importFile"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seems to be made a typo in Directive Definition Object, where `$scope` should be `scope`.

---

I'd like to suggest few things to improve your current approach, rather than using `watcher` in parent controller method. You should pass a callback to directive and call it as soon as you're done with reader object loaded. Which turns out that your isolated scope will appear like below

```
restrict: 'A',
scope: {
    callback: '&'
},
```

and then put new method inside controller where we will pass a file data to that method.

```
$scope.importData = function(data) {
    DataManagementService.importData(newValue);
});
```

And then from element pass callback method correctly on directive

```
<input id="btnImport" type="file" es-file-read callback="importData(data)"/>
```

Call method from directive code correctly.

```
reader.onload = function (loadEvent) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.esFileRead= loadEvent.target.result;
        $scope.callback({ item: $scope.esFileRead });
    });
};
```

Comment: This is awkward. Had `$scope` instead of `scope` in my directive declaration. I'm still accepting your answer because I find it quite neat. Thank you!

Comment: @EpaXapate that wasn't an issue, unless you had 1st parameter name is `$scope`.. Issue must be something else

Comment: I don't mean in the link function, I mean in the actual return function.

Comment: @EpaXapate sorry, I didn't get you :(

Comment: In the definition of the directive (`return {}`) where you define `restrict` and such, having `$scope` instead of `scope` was the issue.